# Window is still resized after opening second time

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I am opening one app in IframeWindow and giving `resizable: true,`. Now When I resize it happening. But problem is when close and again open the window is not coming in correct dimension. It comming in resized size. I wanted to be in correct or original dimension. Any Idea what I have to do.

Thanks In advance

My Code

```
H1 = new Ext.IframeWindow({
                        width: (viewportWidth / 100) * 90,
                        height: (viewportHeight / 100) * 90,
                        modal: true,
                        resizable: true,
                        title: 'Molecular Biomarkers',
                        closable: true,
                        constrain : true,
                        src: Some Path
                    });
```

Comment: Could you create a Sencha Fiddle to better understand what you mean?

Comment: The scenario you are describing may occur when the window has the "closeAction" config set to "hide" instead of "destroy". Try to add closeAction: 'destroy' to your code and double check Ext.IframeWindow class declaration